# Bold text is displayed strange on Chrome / Mac OS

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Since a couple of days, my Chrome is acting really strange. For a lot of websites, if the text hast font-weight: bold; the text is displayed really strange. At source code everything looks good and if i remove font-weight: bold; on inspector, its displayed correctly.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix it?

[image: How it looks]
[image]